# Controlar caracteres especiales al final de un ngFor

Tags: html, angular

estoy realizando una web en donde debo presentar las especialidades de un chef, los datos los recio desde el backend y los presento mediante un ngFor de la siguiente manera:

```
 <div *ngFor="let i of item.specialty; let ultimo =last" >
  <p  style="display: inline-block;"> {{i.name}}, &nbsp; </p>
 </div>
```

Como se ve agregue una coma para que se muestre las diferentes especialidades seguidas por coma, el problema es que al ultimo elemento tambien se agrega una coma, ¿Cómo puedo controlar para que la coma no aparesca en el ultimo elemento que trae el ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ponerle una comparación de si es el último ciclo entonces que no lo muestre:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of item.specialty; let ultimo = item.specialty.length" >
  <p  style="display: inline-block;"> {{i.name}}{{ultimo == i ? '' : ','}} &nbsp; </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de hacerlo seria utilizando la variable last the ngFor, te dejo abajo un link con la documentacion de ngForOf, ahi encontraras el uso de last, first, etc;

```
<div *ngFor="let i of item.specialty; let ultimo = last" >
  <p  style="display: inline-block;"> {{i.name}}{{ultimo ? '' : ','}} &nbsp; </p>
 </div>
```

[Documentación](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)